# Ubuntu not powering off

Tags: uefi, shutdown, bios, reboot, 23.10

I recently installed ubuntu 23.10.1 on my pc on another ssd. It works fine except that it DOES NOT restart or shutdown. Everything comes to an halt after a few seconds of the power off button but the power light does not turn off. Tired UEFI and BIOS, both didn't work.
It used to work fine on ubuntu 23.04 (old hdd) and even updated that one and it worked fine..
Tried fixes from the internet but did not work.

Additional Info:
**Drive (SSD):** VisionTek GoDrive 120 GB 
**PC:** Optiplex 7040 
**CPU:** i5-6500 @ 3.20GHz 
**RAM:** 8 GB DDR4 2133MHz